# C++ Text Game Custom Clock System

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Clock doesn't work. Once it reaches 60 mins, it continues onward without changing hour. Example: 12:75 am, 12:90 am, etc... 
I wanted to build a clock that adds time based on actions. Does not work on real time.

Sorry for the mess, new to Stack Overflow, and sharing code in general. Keep in mind, I'm still new to coding.

```
(All integers used)
-
int timeHour = 0;
string timePMAM = "";
int timeHourDisplay = 0;
int timeHourMax = 12;

int timeMin = 0;
int timeMinDisplay = 00;

int day = 0;
string dayDisplay = "";
if (timeMin == 60)
    {
        timeMinDisplay = 0;
        timeMin = 0;
        timeHour += 1;
        timeHourDisplay += 1;
    }
    if (timeMin > 60)
    {
        timeMinDisplay -= 60;
        timeMin -= 60;
        timeHour += 1;
        timeHourDisplay += 1;
    }
    //Used for changing 60minutes into an hour

    if (timeHour < timeHourMax)
    {
        timePMAM = "am";
    }
    if (timeHour >= timeHourMax)
    {
        timePMAM = "pm";
    }
    //pm and am

    if (timeHour == 13)
    {
        timeHourDisplay = 1;
    }
    // 13 o'clock is now 1 o'clock
    if (timeHour == 24)
    {
        timeHour = 0;
        timeHourDisplay = 12;
        day += 1;
    }
    if (timeHour == 1)
    {
        timeHourDisplay = 1;
    }
    if (timeHour == 0)
    {
        timeHourDisplay = 12;
    }
}
```

Comment: The key questions that must be answered before we can help you is, "What is the clock supposed to do?" and "What is it actually doing instead?"

Comment: I could probably figure out what is wrong by reading the entire block of code, but that's a lot of work, and I'd have to make guesses as to what you actually want.

Comment: This is legitimately unreadable code. Where are the integers used actually implemented in your code? Re-upload your actual code so we can actually read it, also, what it your clock supposed to do?

Comment: Track seconds, convert to HH:MM:SS as needed for display.  No need to fiddle hours/minutes counters up/down as you do time adjustments.  Definitely need a [mcve] though.

Comment: I suppose I could add seconds, but the point is to have time pass due to actions. Seconds kinda seem like they would take space for something I could avoid using. And yes, I should clean this post up. This is my first question here. Kinda guessed it was a little long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using [Howard Hinnant's free, open source date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html).  It takes care of all of the time/calendrical arithmetic for you and has very flexible formatting options.  For example:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string
display_time(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point time)
{
    auto s = date::format("%I:%M %p", time);
    if (s.front() == '0')
        s.erase(0, 1);
    for (auto& c : s)
        c = tolower(c);
    return s;
}

std::string
display_date(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point time)
{
    return date::format("%b %e, %Y", time);
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace date::literals;
    auto time = date::sys_days{2017_y/sep/10} + 75min;

    time += 15min;
    cout << "The walk took 15 minutes: " << display_time(time) << '\n';

    cout << "You lay down on the cold ground and cry yourself to sleep, longing for burrito" << endl;
    time += 8h;
    cout << display_time(time) << endl;

    cout << "The current time is " << display_time(time) << endl;
            cout << "The date is " << display_date(time) << endl;
            cout << "It seems your watch is broken again.." << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
The walk took 15 minutes: 1:30 am
You lay down on the cold ground and cry yourself to sleep, longing for burrito
9:30 am
The current time is 9:30 am
The date is Sep 10, 2017
It seems your watch is broken again..
```

Comment: I thank you for the code, and the recommendation, but I'd rather not use someone else's code. The whole point of this project is to improve my coding knowledge and skills. I'd rather learn and personally create as much of it as I can. Even if that results in the mess that I call code above.

Comment: In that case, learn `<chrono>`, part of the std::lib.  Here is a video tutorial to help you with that:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M

Comment: Thank you very much! Im sure this will be very useful for later uses too. Ill get on it when I can.